# Asp.net Custom Validate. What languages can you use?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, customvalidator, asp.net-validators

I am currently looking at .net custom validate. for a custom rule it looks like you have to set up a validate control in the aspx page like this:

```
      <asp:CustomValidator id="sumcheckValidator" runat="server"  
      ErrorMessage="numbers dont add up correctly" 
      Display="Dynamic"
      ForeColor="Red"
      ClientValidationFunction="sumcheck" />
```

and then create a script. I want to know what languages you can create the script in. I have seen that you can use javascript. But is there anything else available that i can use?

Comment: You should mark as answer if the below given answer is the one you're looking for...

Answer (score 1):

And [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) itself (or the serverside language that your page uses) for [serverside validation (CustomValidator.OnServerValidate)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.onservervalidate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)